# Linux doesn't detect hardware in a Hyper-V VM during installation

Tags: linux, hyper-v, hardware-detection

I've created a Hyper-V Virtual Machine running Linux. It works fine but when I is installing it doesn't recognize the mouse and all of the computer components(eternet card and hard drive). Why?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the integration services for Linux.

The follow link provides the services:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41554

> •Integrated Mouse Support: Linux Integration Services provides full mouse support for Linux guest virtual machines.
>
> •Driver support: Linux Integration Services supports the network
>   controller and the IDE and SCSI storage controllers that were
>   developed specifically for Hyper-V.

Comment: I've tried installing the services but it says that the Linux distro I'm using isn't supported. (I'm using Kali Linux) PS: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=46842 this is an updated version of the services

Comment: Kali is not officialy supported by MS with the use of Hyper-V. There is the problem I think.
http://blogs.technet.com/b/devops/archive/2014/06/17/linux-support-in-hyper-v-virtual-machines.aspx

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531030.aspx

Comment: On another computer it worked just fine. I recognized everything and I could use it. On my computer it doesn't. The two computer are very similar(on my computer there's only more memory)

Comment: Can you copy the exact error that you get when trying to install the integration services?

Comment: It isn't an error it just says that the OS isn't supported. Nothing more, nothing less